# NGRX concat two action

Tags: rxjs, ngrx

I am using NGRX and Angular 11.
I am trying to, when an action is executed, call another action, listen to the success of it, and if it succeeded dispatch a final action:

Here my code a bit simplified :

```
@Effect()
  getUserSettingSuccess$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    // When this action `GetUserSettingsSuccess` is executed
    ofType<featureActions.GetUserSettingsSuccess>(featureActions.ActionTypes.GetUserSettingsSuccess),
    concatMap((action) =>
      of(action).pipe(withLatestFrom(this.store$.pipe(select(ProjectsStoreSelectors.selectedProjectId))))
    ),
    // I want to dispatch a new action 
    tap(([action, projectId]) => new ModelsStoreAction.GetAllModelsRequest({ projectId })),
    // and listen to the success / failure of that action. 
    // If success dispatch `SetModelSelection` else do nothing.
    map(([action]) =>
      this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType(ModelsStoreAction.ActionTypes.GetAllModelsSuccess),
        takeUntil(this.actions$.pipe(ofType(ModelsStoreAction.ActionTypes.GetAllCesiumModelsFailed))),
        first(),
        map(() => new ModelsStoreAction.SetModelSelection())
      )
    )
```

The problem I have is that, the above code do not dispatch a valid action. But I am getting a bit lost with all those rxjs operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here would be my approach:

```js
@Effect()
  getUserSettingSuccess$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    // When this action `GetUserSettingsSuccess` is executed
    ofType<featureActions.GetUserSettingsSuccess>(featureActions.ActionTypes.GetUserSettingsSuccess),
    
    concatMap((action) =>
      of(action).pipe(withLatestFrom(this.store$.pipe(select(ProjectsStoreSelectors.selectedProjectId))))
    ),

    // I want to dispatch a new action 
    tap(([action, projectId]) => new ModelsStoreAction.GetAllModelsRequest({ projectId })),
    
    // and listen to the success / failure of that action. 
    // If success dispatch `SetModelSelection` else do nothing.
    switchMap(
      ([action]) => this.actions$.pipe(
        // adding all the possibilities here
        ofType(ModelsStoreAction.ActionTypes.GetAllModelsSuccess, ModelsStoreAction.ActionTypes.GetAllCesiumModelsFailed),

        first(),
        filter(a => a.type === ModelsStoreAction.ActionTypes.GetAllModelsSuccess.type),
        map(() => new ModelsStoreAction.SetModelSelection()),
      )
    )
  )
```

It didn't work before because `this.actions$` is essentially a type of Subject and an effect is not expected to return an Observable-like value. In order to solve that, I used `switchMap`, which will handle the inner subscription automatically.